# Side navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a navigation bar that appears on the left side of my website when my main navigation (that is located at the center top of my website) is out of screen. How is this called? I've tried searching for it but I have no idea how this effect is called..

Edit:
Something like this sidebar navigation: http://www.bootply.com/73864
But I want to show the sidemenu only when the top menu (in this case: 
Bootstrap 3 Affix Fixed (Sticky) Sidebar Panel) is gone

Comment: You mean 'off-canvas' navigation? Google is your friend.

Comment: Yep, off-canvas navigation. This is my 'starting point' that I've put together if it helps you: https://github.com/kthornbloom/Responsive_Template

Comment: I edited the begin post for a clearer image of my idea

Answer (score 0):

Try using iframes.
For example, this frame, puts a bar on the left side, and when you cal a link later on, you just need to set the target to the frame you wish to use:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Principal</title>
  </head>
 <frameset cols="15%,85%" framespacing="0" scrolling="no" noresize frameborder="0"                 name="principal">
    <frame src="menu.html" name="cima">
    <frame src="mainpage.php" name="baixo" marginwidth="100"></frameset>
 </frameset>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

From here, you call the page you wish to use as a menu to the left, and roll on the rest of your website on the right! And whenever you browse to a different page, as long as you call on the correct target, your menu will always be on your left

Comment: Does not answer the question. the issue is "off-canvas" navigation.